# Apache Nifi, how to get JSON from API

Tags: json, api, rest, apache-nifi

I've started using Apache Nifi and I'm still learning it and experimenting with it. I really want to use Nifi to get JSON documents from API's and put them in my Elasticsearch database. So far using the built-in getTwitter and putElasticsearch controllers this works.

However now I want to do this with other APIs than Twitter, and I'm kinda stuck here. First off I really don't even know which controller to use? I would think getHttp or invokeHttp even with 'GET' as http verb then but it doesn't seem to work. If I use the getHttp I have to give an SSL service with keystore and truststore .. like why would I have to do that?

Apache Nifi is still quite new so hard to find decent guides / information about these kinds of things. I have read and searched the documentation but haven't gotten the wiser.

An example JSON to pick up from an API is:

https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/getEndpointData?host=www.bnpparibasfortis.be&s=193.58.4.82

Thanks in advance for anyone that can offer some help / insight.

Answer (score 3):

What processor you use to get the JSON data is entirely dependent on the API you want to hit. The GetHttp or InvokeHttp processors should work to grab the data from a URL. If you'll notice, the SSL service is an optional property for both GetHttp and InvokeHttp so you only need to you use it when you want to communicate via HTTPS. Also, from the UI you can right click on a processor and then click "usage" to bring up the documentation for that processor.

At this link[1] you can find a NiFi template that uses GetHttp to get JSON data from randomuser.me and does various processing on it. It's primarily a template to show-case the different Avro processors but the method of grabbing the JSON should be relevant.

[1]  https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/nifi-templates/blob/master/templates/Convert_To_Avro_From_CSV_and_JSON.xml

Comment: I just made a keystore and used the standard java truststore and then it worked!